# Pages organisation of jquery mobile app

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

In my HTML5 / JQueryMobile app, I use several data-role="page" divs in the same index.html file:

```
<body>
  <!-- Map page -->
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="map">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Map</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
       <div id="map_canvas" style="width:320px; height:300px; float:left; border: 1px solid black;">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
       <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#map" class="ui-btn-active">Map</a></li>
             <li><a href="#list">List</a></li>
             <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- List page -->
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="list">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>List</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        … 
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
       <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#map">Map</a></li>
             <li><a href="#list" class="ui-btn-active">List</a></li>
             <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Settings page -->
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="b id="settings">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Settings</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        ...
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
       <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#map">Map</a></li>
             <li><a href="#list">List</a></li>
             <li><a href="#settings" class="ui-btn-active">Settings</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This code does not work very nicely. The selected item of the navigation is not well highlighted after several clicks.
Is this page structure (several data-role="page" in the body) the correct way to do ?

**UPDATE**

Seems to be the way to do it (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/#docs/pages/docs-pages.html), so I must miss something.

Comment: You're HTML is not valid, in the Settings page the data-theme="b should have a closing quote and there is a extra div at the botom of the page

Comment: @phill-pafford, sorry for the typo. But same thing with the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Alpha version 1, they have improved much with Alpha version 4: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-pages.html

You might also have a look at the toolbar section as well:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/index.html

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jAwPR/3/